# Format array output to be readable by chartjs in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dictionary, chart.js

This is my query to get the product name and total quantity sold.

```
 $prd = DB::table('order_details')
        ->join('products', 'order_details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('products.name', DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as quantity'))
        ->groupBy('products.name')
        ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
        ->get();
        
    return $prd;
```

This is the output.

```
[
  {
  "name": "PINK",
  "quantity": "22"
  },
  {
  "name": "WHITE",
  "quantity": "14"
  },
  {
  "name": "RED",
  "quantity": "13"
  }
]
```

But I need it to be in this format. For it to work with chartjs.

```
{
  "PINK": 22,
  "WHITE": 14,
  "RED": 13
}
```

This is what I've so far. I tried to use collection map. But I'm not sure how to return the quantity portion. Any pointers?

```
return $prd->groupBy('name')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return ''; // what should I return here to get the qty?
});
```

Current half baked output

```
{
  "PINK": "",
  "WHITE": "",
  "RED": "",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) instead of `get()` for this:

```
$prd = DB::table('order_details')
    ->join('products', 'order_details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('products.name', DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as quantity'))
    ->groupBy('products.name')
    ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
    ->pluck('name', 'quantity');
```

Comment: But pluck will have double quotes on the quantity. Is there a way to remove the double quotes?

{
  "PINK": "22",
  "WHITE": "14",
  "RED": "13",
}